# Fetch the book info with the ISBN number via Amazon WebServices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I need to connect to Amazon WebServices to get the info of a book with the ISBN number given by the user.

The problem is that I don`t know how to do this. 
I don´t have found any good documentation to do this in google.

I am newbie in rails. So, anybody can give tips to do this?

Which is the best gem to connect to Amazon WebServices with Rest? 
Which is exactly the name of the webservice of Amazon to get the book info?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html), which is an Amazon Web Service, but generally not treated like other AWS services. That link has the official documentation. I [wrote a blog post](http://blog.engelke.com/2011/12/11/chrome-web-app-bookshelf-part-3/) on doing this at a low level with JavaScript, which you could use to build Ruby code if you can't find a high level SDK for it.

Answer (score 0):

there are several gems out there for accessing the product advertising API.

one of those is asin: https://github.com/phoet/asin

you can see a running version using rails here: http://asin.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a "[lookup by ISBN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html)" in the product advertising API.

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
  Service=AWSECommerceService
  &Operation=ItemLookup
  &ResponseGroup=Large
  &SearchIndex=All
  &IdType=ISBN
  &ItemId=076243631X
  &AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyID]
  &AssociateTag=[Your_AssociateTag]
  &Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
  &Signature=[Request_Signature]
```